# Attempt to use a closed cursor: "ProgrammingError"

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, sql-insert

I am trying to insert a `.csv` file's contents into a SQL Server database.

Here is my code:

```
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("Truncate table HumanResources.DepartmentTest") # Truncate old table contents

# Insert Dataframe into SQL Server:
    
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO HumanResources.DepartmentTest (DepartmentID,Name,GroupName) values(?,?,?)", row.DepartmentID, row.Name, row.GroupName)
        cnxn.commit()
        cursor.close()
```

I am running above code in my lambda function. Not sure why I am getting this error;

> "errorMessage": "Attempt to use a closed cursor."
> "errorType": "ProgrammingError"
>
> "stackTrace":
> "  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 56, in  lambda_handler\n    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO HumanResources.DepartmentTest (DepartmentID,Name,GroupName) values(?,?,?)", row.DepartmentID, row.Name, row.GroupName)

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: All indentation is incorrect. Is this your real code?

Comment: yes. although table name is diff here.

Comment: corrected al indentation. no errors found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `cursor.close()` should be outside of the for loop:

```
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO HumanResources.DepartmentTest (DepartmentID,Name,GroupName) values(?,?,?)", row.DepartmentID, row.Name, row.GroupName)
        cnxn.commit()
    cursor.close()
```